# Add "target= '_blank' " to an anchor tag excluding a given id

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add  a `target=_blank` attribute to an anchor tag, except a button and certain div. How do I not add target attribute to "call-control" class and ID with #?

I've tried this:

```js
$('a:not(.call-control,"#")').attr('target', '_blank').addClass('checkMate');

/* then later... */
$('.checkMate').attr("target", "");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="call-control">
  <span id="incomingCallBrand"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="comms-icon" id="iambusy"></a>
  <span>Peter</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML to help [demonstrate the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1. Add `target=_blank` to all of your `a` tag including `.call-control` and `#`
----------
2. Select the `.call-control` and `#` and remove `target=_blank` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of what specific links you're trying to select, your selector is invalid.

To apply the selection to any links that don't have a certain **class**, you're looking for `$("a:not('.class')")`:

To apply the selection to any links that don't have a certain **class**, you're looking for `$("a:not('[href=#'])")`:

These can be combined as `$("a:not('.class-control, [href=#]')")`:

```js
$("a:not('.call-control, [href=#]')").attr("target", "_blank").addClass('checkMate');
```

```css
.checkMate {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="call-control" href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer">Same Page (doesn't get the target)</a>
<br />
<a class="call-control" href="http://www.google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer">Google (doesn't get the target)</a>
<br />
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" rel="noopener noreferrer">Facebook (gets the target)</a>
```

Also, it's important to note that `target=_blank` has a significant **[security vulnerability](https://dev.to/ben/the-targetblank-vulnerability-by-example/)**, which can be exploited with `window.opener()`. This can be **[seen here](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/)**. To fix this, you also need to add `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to your links (as above).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: i want to exclude the class with name ".call-control" and a tags who does not have href='#'

Comment: @PrabinPoudel -- I've updated my answer to cover exactly that =]

Comment: Thank you @bsidian-age , it works as i want but i have not used the rel="" field as it doesnot effett much in my context.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to select an element that has neither the class "call-control" nor an `href` set to "#", using [jQuery's `.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method.

To select elements without `href` set to "#", I suggest [jQuery's "Attribute Equals" Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
.not([href=#])
```

Adding the class requirement:

```
.not([href=#],.call-control)
```

I also recommend [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) as opposed to setting the `target` to a blank string.

Here's an example:

```js
$('a:not([href=#],.call-control)').attr('target', '_blank').addClass('checkMate');

/* remove the attribute after one second */
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.checkMate').removeAttr('target');
},1000);
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

.checkMate {
  background-color:pink;
}

/* to demonstrate when the target has been removed */
a[target=_blank] {
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="call-control">Class and HREF</a>
<a href="page.html" class="call-control">Just Class</a>
<a href="#">Just HREF</a>
<a href="http://example.com">Neither Class nor HREF</a>
```

For reference:
[Add a class to a href that's set to '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674304/add-a-class-to-a-href-thats-set-to)